# How to change name (NOT USERNAME) on Github? My nickname is showing up next to my name in parenthesis on Github and I need to change it,

Tags: github

Whenever I make a commit to my Github profile, I see my nickname and then my real name in parenthesis next to it on Github. The problem is, whenever I go to my profile it just has my real name there. For professional reasons, I need to update this so that just my real name appears. I set up my Github profile a few years ago before I knew anything about programming so don't remember how I did this. I've attached pictures.

Photo of my nickname followed by real name in parenthesis

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f14yQ.jpg):https://i.stack.imgur.com/meTuC.jpg)

Photo of profile that just has my real first and last name

[image: 1]

I've tried editing profile, going to individual organizations and changing the name and neither works

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the answer. Just had to do 'git config --global user.name "My Name"' and it worked.